# Pass props to HTML content in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, redux

I'm using webview component to load my html inside RN app.I need to display some props with in the html content.how do I do that?

Comment: Please add chunk of your code, so we can help you

Comment: What do you mean by some props in the html content?